# Any way to raise an error when getting the function instead of running it

Tags: javascript

A common error:

```
a = myfunction;
```

...instead of:

```
a = myfunction();
```

Any way to avoid this?

In case we have this function inside an object, could I to say something to the object to avoid return functions and require execution?

Comment: That's a valid JavaScript statement and throwing an error makes no sense.

Comment: I know...but only if you want to get a function

Answer (score 3):

You can use `typeof` to check if it's a function:

```
a = myfunction;
var result;

if (typeof a == "function")
    // a was set to myfunction, not myfunction()
    result = a();
else
    // a was presumably set to myfunction() and not myfunction
    result = a;
```

This way you can call the function if it is indeed a function, otherwise you can do something else with it, assuming that's what you're wanting to do.

Comment: That was an incredibly fast downvote, care to explain the reasoning for it?

Comment: Not my downvote, but I understood the question as the OP wanting to reduce unwanted bugs when they accidentally type `a = myfunction;` when they actually wanted to type `a = myfunction();`. This won't help there.

Comment: But `a = myfunction` won't produce any errors. It's a valid JS statement.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, that's the OP's problem. The interpreter doesn't catch the mistake.

Comment: @Juhana it would help in that if you declared `a = myfunction` you could then check to see if `a` is a function (and execute `a()` instead of assuming the function has already been executed).

Comment: This actually doesn't answer the question. OP knows `myFunction` is a function (and he/she **must** know it). He/she wants a mind-reader that catches the programmer's errors.